# Label Normalization in Deep Regression Networks

Tags: neural-network, regression, deep-learning

In regression problems there is typically no reason for normalizing/rescaling the labels (targets) before performing the optimization.

In deep regression networks there would be in principle no need to rescale since the last activation function is linear and the cost function is the mean squared difference of the predictions from the targets.

On the other hand, for numerical stability and performance of the training process, the values of the input and hidden units are kept in the range [-1,1] via feature normalization. Doesn't it mean that the labels should be rescaled to the range [-1,1] too?

Answer (score 1):

traditionally in regression problems, you `denormalize` the output generated